# How do I configure the java.home in a agent of a hudson server?

Tags: windows, hudson, java-home

I am using a windows box to run the agent for my husdon. But I haven't found any effect way to configure JAVA_HOME and PATH for java on the box.

Does anyone know how I am able to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can configure where Jenkins/Hudson should search for the JDK on the agent on the Manage Nodes configuration page (`${JENKINS_URL}/computer`).

Check "Tool Locations", Click "Add", select the JDK from the List and type the path to the JDK in the "Home" text field below.

**If JDK isn't showing up in the Tool Locations list,** it may be because **you need to configure a JDK globally first**. To do this, check the "JDK" section in your global configuration page.

Comment: +1 This working a seldom built project, then it just stopped - suspect somebody changed the global setting.  Setting the JDK in the project might be more robust that setting as global.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer - I don't see JDK in the list of tools I can add locations for. I see Git, WindowsGit, Maven, and SonarRunner. How can I make JDK appear?

Comment: Finally got it to appear in the list... I'm realizing the original answer actually contained what I needed to know but I overlooked it. I'm editing the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! The german translation of the page makes it even harder to find the setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your Jenkins version, it will solve it. Otherwise this worked for me (Jenkins 1.6, build/test node: MacOSX Mojave):

First install java 8 **in your build/test node** using the commands:

```
brew update
brew cask install caskroom/versions/java8
```

Then in Jenkins web panel click on your build/test node, then click on **Configure** and then click in the **Advanced...** button, this will show you multiple text fields. Then in the JavaPath field add the path to your java 8.

[image]

For me this path is like:

`/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.X_XXX.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java`

**Note:** remember replace `X_XXX` with your java 8 version before.

Then **Save**.

After that disconnect the build/test node and connect it again. This should solve the problem.